# DynamoDB .Net limit a scan that uses 'begins with'

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

This code uses Dynamo but is coded in C#.

I have a scan that uses a scanFilter:

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable(amazonClient, tableName);
ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter();
scanFilter.AddCondition("HashString", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, index);
Search search = table.Scan(scanFilter); // more code follows utilising the results
```

// index is the value of the string to be searched

// amazonClient is just the parameter for AWS

// tableName is the Name of the Table

This works fine as is, but I now understand the number items returned could be massive, so I need either to limit the number of values that are returned in any return page or limit the number of items that are searched (less desireable), and obtain the LastKeyEvaluated. My problem is I can't see how to achieve a limit to this method, how to get the LastKeyevaluated, and lastly, if I have the LastKeyEvaluated how to get the next set of results.

I've looked at using a ScanRequest, which appears to allow a limit, but I can't see how I can add a 'BeginsWith' filter expression?  Nor how to utilise the LasKeyEvaluated

I'd appreciate a suggestionthat works with .Net

Many thanks

Ellie

Answer (score 0):

When you call table.Scan that does not actually do the scan yet. It sets up the underling request objects from the AmazonDynamoDBClient. On the search object that is returned you can call GetNextSet() which is the equivalent of calling Scan just once on the AmazonDynamoDBClient. If you call GetNextSet again the search object maintained the state of the LastKeyEvaluated and passes it along on the next.